# How to declare 2D matrices in CUDA dynamically

Tags: cuda, cuda-gdb

As a part of my code , I am trying to use 2D matrices in CUDA , but it always give me segmentation fault.

```
double** d_matrix;
cudaMalloc((void**)&d_matrix, m * sizeof(double*));

for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_matrix[i], n * sizeof(double));
}
```

when I run this using gdb i get

```
  Thread 1 "qr" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
  0x00007ffff5be2ba0 in ?? () from 
 /usr/lib/wsl/drivers/nvdmi.inf_amd64_706343011d139b51/libcuda.so.1.1
 
  (gdb) backtrace
  #0  0x00007ffff5be2ba0 in ?? () from 
  /usr/lib/wsl/drivers/nvdmi.inf_amd64_706343011d139b51/libcuda.so.1.1
  #1  0x0000555555585f73 in cudart::driverHelper::mallocPtr(unsigned long, void**) ()
  #2  0x000055555556154b in cudart::cudaApiMalloc(void**, unsigned long) ()
  #3  0x0000555555596aec in cudaMalloc ()
  #4  0x000055555555bd04 in main () at qr.cu:58
```

what is the error?

Comment: `cudaMalloc` requires an address in host memory to initialize.  The second instance in your example is passing an address in device memory, which is illegal usage of `cudaMalloc`. The case in the linked duplicate/canonical that most closely resembles what you have shown so far is the “general, dynamically allocated 2D case”, but you may wish to study the other methodologies discussed there as well.